# Btrfs - Using Flash Drive as Backup/Snapshot Location

Tags: debian, filesystems, backup, usb-drive, btrfs

I am working on a project where I have a small MiniITX PC running Debian Jessie (8.3)

When I installed the OS initially:

- I chose the filesystem as btrfs.
- I am not using LVM or any extra partitions except for swap.
- No encryption on drive.

With everything I want/need installed, the entire space used by my system is about 4GB. I don't anticipate using much more than another gig.. ever.

Additionally, I have an empty 16GB flash drive formatted to btrfs.

With this being the setup:
**(tl;dr) How can I make backups (snapshots?) of my running Debian System, and store them on the flash drive?**

Ideally, this is so that if something catastrophic happens to my main hard drive, I could restore it back to a good working condition by utilizing what was saved to the flash drive.

Can someone please spell this out for me?

**Debian HDD**:

- /dev/sda1 is the mountpoint for /   Format: BTRFS
- /dev/sda2 is the extended partition
- /dev/sda5 is the Linux Swap (6gb)

**Flash Drive**:

- /dev/sdb1    Mounted to: /mnt/USB1  Format: BTRFS

btrfs-tools are installed.

**I just want to know the commands to accomplish this:**

1. How to make a snapshot of my entire /
2. How to back this up to my flash drive
3. How to restore it if everything gets majorly screwed up.

Thank you **very much** in advance. My sanity is waning..

Comment: Take a look at [Borg Backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.org/en/stable/).

Comment: @FaheemMitha This is fantastic! Learning curve a bit, but it certainly does what I want! Thanks! I'd like to leave the question open for a bit though, as I am interested in BTRFS native functions.

Comment: Good. Glad you found it of interest.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yeah! I spent 4-5 hours playing with it and testing it out. This is absolutely off topic from question.. But I notice if I use sudo to backup and restore, the restored file permissions are all set to root:root. If I do everything from root console, it seems to retain normal properties. Is that normal?

Comment: I think it should retain all the file properties that it originally had. If you want to chat, come to the main chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat. You can ping me there. I suggest asking questions about Borg Backup on IRC. The main dev, Thomas, is in the IRC channel most of the time.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will. Are you US time, or Europe?

Comment: Neither. I'm in India.

Comment: Perfect  I'm in Europe. A bit closer times. Tomorrow! Thanks again for your help

Comment: BTW, the channel is #borkbackup on freenode. If you don't already have an irc client you like, then try irccloud.com.